# Avalonia Camera Barcode/QRCode Scanning

Tags: c#, qr-code, barcode, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm developing a simple Inventory Management System app for a friend's shop.

I have to scan  a barcode/QRCode (using the camera) to load/unload the product in stock.

I think the best way for barcode reading is using *ZXing.Net*.
But I'm using the camera? Is there an easy way to do it?

I've been looking for a solution but I feel lost.
I found *Camera.MAUI* solutions.. but I'm using *Avalonia*.

Any tips or useful links?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For merchant operations, you do not need any of that. You need a hardware barcode/QR reader device, which are cheap and available online (cca $20 give or take), they usually hook up to USB and act as a keyboard. Meaning when you scan an item, it "appears" as if someone typed in the barcode value on a keyboard. So, you organize your app that way. Either have an edit box to accept the code, or track keyboard entry until you recognize a full code.

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution for a desktop software. But what about a mobile app? I should use the device camera.. but i dont know if exists something that can simplify my development

Comment: @DavidePavani, ah, ok, you should have added a tag for mobile platform or specified in the text. Unfortuantely, Avalonia is a cross-platform GUI framework, not general purpose framework. You will need a custom solution for every platform you want to use, Android or iOS. Xamarin has a Camera2 API implementation, but taht drags XAamrin bindings with it. At this point, I think if you need it you would have to make your own using Google API. https://developer.android.com/training/camera2

Comment: Is not a big application, I could rewrite It in Maui platform and use Camera.MAUI + Zxing for mobile. It should be easier. But i Will surely take a look. Thanks for your tips